# gwt using jquery effect possible?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt, uibinder

in my gwt, i have a button that fire like below to create new widget

```
 @UiHandler("buttonfire")
  void addNewWidget(ClickEvent event) {


     htmlPanelHolder.add(new MyCustomWidget(),"placeholder");

 }
```

how to use jquery so that when the MyCustomWidget() show on screen it is using jquery "fadein" effect

i already tried putting jsni to call jquery inside new MyCustomWidget()  onload() but doesnt work.  can guide me on this?

Comment: You can try something like this: 1)Create widget 2) Set widget's css display property to "display:none" 3) Add widget to htmlPanelHolder 4) Call JSNI method: public static native void fadeInWidget() /*-{
  $("mywidget:hidden").fadeIn("slow");
}-*/;

Comment: @Xo4yHaMope  . for step4, should i call fadeInWidget() in step 1 widget constructor after initwidget() ? or should i call fadeInWidget()  inside onload() ?   .  also, $("mywidget:hidden") , is this the id=? for htmlPanelHolder  ?

Comment: You should call fadeInWidget() at the very end, so calling it after initwidget() should work. And sorry there is mistake in jQuery code it should be like: $('#myDivId').fadeIn("slow");  or  $('.myCssClass').fadeIn("slow");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's also possible to create a fade in effect without using jQuery. If you want to do that, just write an Animation class like this:

```
public class FadeInAnimation extends Animation {
    private final UIObject uiObject;

    FadeInAnimation(final UIObject uiObject) {
      this.uiObject = uiObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(final double progress) {
      uiObject.getElement().getStyle().setOpacity(progress);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it on any widget:

```
new FadeInAnimation(myWidget).run(5000);
```

**Note:** The call to `getStyle().setOpacity(..)` even takes care of the special case IE6/7, where it sets `style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (value * 100) + ')';`

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Just used it in on my web site.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with the GQuery library: http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Answer (score 2):

use the [fadeIn effect of GwtQuery](http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gwtquery-core/javadoc/com/google/gwt/query/client/plugins/Effects.html#fadeIn%28com.google.gwt.query.client.Function...%29)