# Problem with The Marquee Tag and GWT

Tags: gwt, marquee

I am trying to get some scrolling text on my web page. The
solution I found is to create a static empty marquee tag on the page
and the access it with the DOM parser and set my text with
setInnerHTML method. (The text I put in is dynamic and comes from the
server)

Anyway the text show up correctly but serverous glitches appear with
the animation.
Sometimes it just dont start sometimes it start and scroll too fast...

Is there any solution to fix that or replace the marquee tag  with another type of text scrolling.

Im using GWT 2.2!

This is my marquee Tag

```
       <MARQUEE id="marquee" onMouseOver=this.stop() onMouseOut=this.start() scrollAmount=7 direction="left" width=100% height=20%/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Marquee generally doesn't work very well - it's basically a deprecated element (see the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) on this topic).

However, if you need a marquee, you could

- either code it as a JavaScript animation (could produce relatively high CPU load!),
- or use the ["silky smooth marquee" solution](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/), which is a jQuery plugin that uses "native functions of the browser" (at least that's what they say) for the scrolling, and works pretty well.

Comment: Two questions: a. when/where do I call the java script that's used to substitute marquee out? Note that we're talking about GWT here, so the elements do not exist after the page is loaded. b. This does not seem to support seamless/cylindrical marquees. Are you aware of a solution that does? Thank you.

Comment: @RAY: a.) JavaScript calls can be made from GWT using [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) (just pass your DOM element as a parameter to the JSNI method) - alternatively, you can create an Animation class directly in GWT (similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4258443/291741)).